# DNS stop working in Windows 10 after several hours

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns

I have a problem on my computer, which I don't know how to solve. After I reboot computer everything works ok. After some hours all sites stop working in browser. If you use IP as address it's ok. Only DNS is not working. Computers from the same net works ok with no problem. So I expect it's not a router problem. Ping works ok.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -t

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=60
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=60
```

But NSlookup is not working:

```
nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** UnKnown can't find google.com: No response from server
```

I tried other DNS servers like 1.1.1.1. It works on other computer or after reboot.

I tried many things proposed in guides for similar problems like:

```
ipconfig /registerdns 
ipconfig /release 
ipconfig /renew
```

If I reboot, or just logoff from current user and login again DNS start to work for 3-4 hours. After 3-4 hours problem appears again.

Comment: Have you tried another DNS resolver, such as Cloudflare, https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/, or tried setting resolution to automatic?

Comment: Yes, I tried 1.1.1.1 it works on other computer in network, but don't work on my PC.

>> tried setting resolution to automatic?

What does it mean?

Comment: "Obtain DNS server address automatically" https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10